# how i can lock a javacard with a secret key?

Tags: javacard

I installed an applet on my javacard without any problem, the problem now is that anyone can delete this applet or install another applet,so I want to lock the card, how I can do this ?? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro#lock--unlock-usage

And be sure to save the new key to somewhere safe.

Answer (score 2):

> the problem now is that anyone can delete this applet or install
>   another applet,so I want to lock the card

This is wrong! In the `Locked` life cycle state must of card's functions are disabled and you can't work with regular applets anymore. To aim your goal, you must change the authentication keys and keep the new keys safely in secret.

For changing the authentication keys, you can use *[GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro#lock--unlock-usage)* tool as below:

```
gp -lock NewKey
```

*Note that for the above command I assumed that your card keys are configured on default values now. If those are set on default value, the above command may break your card.*